# Is there any functional difference between these code in destructuring object?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

While I'm using destructuring assignment to assign variables from arrays, I find another way of destructing. Is there any difference between these two codes?

This is a challenge from freeCodeCamp using javascript, ES6.

```
const LOCAL_FORECAST = {
  today: { min: 72, max: 83 },
  tomorrow: { min: 73.3, max: 84.6 }
};

function get_MaxOfTmrw(forecast) 
{
    const {tomorrow:{max : max_OfTomorrow}} = forecast;

    return max_OfTomorrow;
}

function get_MaxOfTmrw(forecast) 
{

    const {max : max_OfTomorrow}} = forecast.tomorrow;

    return max_OfTomorrow;
}

console.log(get_MaxOfTmrw(LOCAL_FORECAST));
```

Comment: second `get_MaxOfTmrw` has an error. Missing `{` before `max_OfTomorrow`.

Comment: they are the same (without typos). you could move the destructuring into the parameter section, like `function get_MaxOfTmrw({ tomorrow: { max } }) {
        return max;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a difference only if it requires default values

```
function get_MaxOfTmrw(forecast)
{
    const { tomorrow: { max : max_OfTomorrow  = 0 } = {} } = forecast
    return max_OfTomorrow
}

function get_MaxOfTmrw(forecast) 
{
    const { max : max_OfTomorrow = 0 } = forecast.tomorrow; // what if tomorrow is undefined?
    return max_OfTomorrow;
}
```